# Create new variable based on the order of values in other columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame relative to accesses to a website. Several accesses per day, with different possible actions and descriptions of the actions

```
People | Date       | Time  | Action | Descr  | 
       |            |       |        |        | 
j      | 01/01/2010 | 10:13 | X      | A      | 
j      | 01/01/2010 | 10:15 | Y      | B      | 
j      | 02/01/2010 | 14:15 | Z      | C      | 
j      | 03/01/2010 | 11:45 | X      | D      | 
j      | 03/01/2010 | 13:56 | X      | E      | 
j      | 03/01/2010 | 18:43 | Z      | F      | 
j      | 03/01/2010 | 18:44 | X      | A      |
```

After reducing the data frame to a balanced daily panel data, I need to create variables such that:

-the value of the first variable (FirstX) must be equal to the description (Descr) of the first Action = X of the day (if available) and zero otherwise

-the value of the second variable must be equal to the description of the second Action = X of the day and zero otherwise

-so on

Once I transformed it into a balanced daily panel (which I can do) I need to have a final result which looks like this:

```
People | Date       |Accesses| First X|Second X| Third X| Fourth X |
       |            |        |        |        |        |          |
j      | 01/01/2010 |    2   |   A    |   0    |    0   |    0     |
j      | 02/01/2010 |    1   |   0    |   0    |    0   |    0     |
j      | 03/01/2010 |    4   |   D    |   E    |    A   |    0     |
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: @akrun I edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. I post it here in case this is useful to somebody.

```
# create temp variables to be used for the count(just a vector of all the 
numbers from 1 to N)
subset$temp_var1<-c(1:N)


# generate a variable which starts counting from one and starts again 
# every time "date" or "people" change
subset$count<-ave(subset$temp_var1 , subset$date , 
subset$people ,  FUN = seq_along)

#drop variable "Action" 
subset<-subset( subset, select=c("people" , "date" , 
"descr" , "count"))

#reshape
subset_comuni<-reshape(subset_comuni , idvar=c("nome_utente" , "date") , 
timevar = "count" , direction = "wide")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>% 
group_by(People,Date) %>% 
summarise(Accesses = n(),
FirstX = ifelse(sum(Action=="X")>=1,Descr[Action=="X"][1],"0"),
SecondX = ifelse(sum(Action=="X")>=2,Descr[Action=="X"][2],"0"),
ThirdX = ifelse(sum(Action=="X")>=3,Descr[Action=="X"][3],"0"),
FourthX = ifelse(sum(Action=="X")>=4,Descr[Action=="X"][4],"0"))
```

This returns:

```
  People      Date   Accesses FirstX SecondX ThirdX FourthX
   <chr>      <chr>    <int>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
1      j 01/01/2010        2      A       0      0       0
2      j 02/01/2010        1      0       0      0       0
3      j 03/01/2010        4      D       E      A       0
```

Note that you cannot have numeric 0s and characters in the same vector, so I put character 0s in the FirstX, SecondX, .. columns.

Comment: thank you for your answer but this does a completely different thing. it gives me huge numerical values as output and I don't even understand where they do come from

Comment: That's odd.. I can't reproduce your problem. Do you get this issue with the example dataframe you've given in the question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I didn't try with the example dataframe but my dataframe is extremely similar to that. I don't get your code though, why do you use sum()?

Comment: `Action=="X"` returns a logical vector, with values of `TRUE` and `FALSE`. When you take the `sum` of it, it gives you the number of `TRUE` values in the vector as the numeric value of `TRUE` is 1 and the numeric value of `FALSE` is 0. For example, `sum(c(T,T,T,F))` returns 3.